# How can I solve Warning: Expected `onChange` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type in @uiw/react-md-editor for nextjs 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using @uiw/react-md-editor as a markdown editor in my nextjs 13 app. It also has a feature to preview markdown using `MDEditor.Markdown`.
But I am getting this error :
Warning: Expected `onChange` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type.
Also I have to make the component client side.

I tried to use:

```
"use client";

import MDEditor from '@uiw/react-md-editor';
import { useTheme } from 'next-themes';


const PostContent = ({ content }) => {
    const { theme } = useTheme();
    return (
        <div className="py-2 px-3 max-md:px-2">
            <div>
                {<MDEditor.Markdown wrapperElement={{ "data-color-mode": theme }} source={content} style={{ background: "transparent" }} />}
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default PostContent
```

But got the following error:

```
Warning: Expected `onChange` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type.
mdeditor
div
ReactMarkdown@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/react-markdown/lib/react-markdown.js:88:42
div
__webpack_exports__.default<@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@uiw/react-markdown-preview/esm/index.js:54:9
div
div
PostContent@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./src/components/posts/PostContent.jsx:10:23
div
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20309:41
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20309:41
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20479:41
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20309:41
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
Suspense
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20309:41
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20479:41
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20309:41
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
Suspense
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20309:41
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20479:41
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
div
div
div
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20309:41
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20309:41
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20309:41
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20479:41
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20309:41
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20309:41
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20309:41
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20479:41
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21829:32
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Warning: Expected `onChange` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type.
```

As per the above warning problem seems to be coming from component which uses
`<MDEditor>` (that part which gives writing functionality,
which you imported from `import MDEditor from '@uiw/react-md-editor';`)

**This component has a onChange event listener, which you need to set as the function which sets the new state.**
*(Also one more thing I was not able to find wrapperElement prop in documentation)*

**To Support dark-mode/night-mode** :
Please Read this section
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@uiw/react-md-editor#support-dark-modenight-mode

**See the 1st example given here on there official NPM Page:**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@uiw/react-md-editor#support-nextjs

There is a state & its function to set state

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState("**Hello world!!!**");
```

Then pass this setValue function to MdEditor Component

```
<MDEditor
        value={value}
        onChange={setValue}
      />
```

I wrote some code on my side got no issues NextJS  Version (13.5.6) & also Imported that preview component in a page & passed a value it worked.

**Writer.js Component**

```
'use client'
import React from 'react'
import MDEditor from '@uiw/react-md-editor';
import PreviewMD from './PreviewMD';
import { useTheme } from 'next-themes';

const Writer = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState("**Hello world!!!**");
    const { theme } = useTheme()

    return (
        <div data-color-mode={theme}>
            <h1>Writer</h1>

            <MDEditor
                value={value}
                onChange={setValue}
            />

            <div>
                <PreviewMD content={value} />
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Writer
```

**PreviewMD.js Component**

Imported this on a page & passed
`content={"**Hello world!!!**"}` worked properly

```
'use client'
import React from 'react'
import MDEditor from '@uiw/react-md-editor';

const PreviewMD = ({ content }) => {

    return (
        <div >
            <h1>Preview </h1>

            <MDEditor.Markdown
                source={content}
                style={{ background: "transparent" }}
            />

        </div>
    )
}

export default PreviewMD
```

**Versions of libraries** (its inside package.json)

```
"dependencies": {
    "@uiw/react-md-editor": "^3.24.1",
    "next": "^13.5.6",
    "next-themes": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
```

***Please make other necessary changes wherever required.***